# Aligning output in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way where I can right-align my output in such a way like this:

```
 Item: $  13.69
  Tax: $   5.30
  Oth: $   2.50  
---------------
Total: $  99.80
```

Please note that I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `.format` method of strings to do this:

```
fmt = '{0:>5}: ${1:>6.2f}'
print(fmt.format('Item', 13.69)) # Prints ' Item: $  13.69'
print(fmt.format('Tax', 5.3)) 
print(fmt.format('Oth', 2.5))
print('-'*len(fmt.format('Item', 13.69))) # Prints as many '-' as the length of the printed strings
print(fmt.format('Total', 99.8))
# etc...
```

The '{0:>5}' part is saying "take the zeroth item given to `.format`, and right justify it within 5 spaces".  The '{1:>6.2f}' part is saying take the first item given to `.format`, right justify it within 6 spaces, formatting as a decimal with 2 decimal places.

Of course, in real code this would likely be part of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  the same amount of spaces before the text with all of the items you want to align.

Another option would be to use the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) operator as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment).

Comment: using the same amount of tabs would not work if there are significant >4 letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting:

```
print("$%6s" % dec_or_string)
```