# Right Justify python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I justify the output of this code?

```
N = int(input())
case = '#'
print(case)

for i in range(N):
    case += '#'
    print(case)
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `format` with `>` to right justify

```
N = 10
for i in range(1, N+1):
    print('{:>10}'.format('#'*i))
```

Output

```
         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########
```

You can programattically figure out how far to right-justify using `rjust` as well.

```
for i in range(1, N+1):
    print(('#'*i).rjust(N))
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you might be looking for rjust:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust

```
my_string = 'foo'
print my_string.rjust(10)
'       foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

The `string.format()` method has this as part of its syntax.

```
print "{:>10}".format(case)
```

The number in the string tells python how many characters long the string should be, even if it's larger than the length of `case`. And the greater than sign tells it to right justify `case` within that space.

Answer (score 1):

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(N+1):
    print(" "*(N-i) + "#"*(i+1))
```

Print the right number of spaces followed by the right number of the "#" characters.

Answer (score 1):

One liner using f-string and join:

```
print("\n".join([f"{'#' * i:>10}" for i in range(1, 11)]))
```

Output:

```
         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########
```

If you would like to include row number you can do following:

```
print("\n".join([f"{i:<3}{'#' * i:>10}" for i in range(1, 11)]))
```

Output:

```
1           #
2          ##
3         ###
4        ####
5       #####
6      ######
7     #######
8    ########
9   #########
10 ##########
```