# Is it possible to append spaces and a certain amount of spaces to a string?

Tags: python, string

Here is my current code. The question is exactly in the title. (I'm looking to be able to align my triangle correctly)

```
def Triangle(height):
    if height % 2 == 0:
        print "Please enter a height that is odd"

    else:
        stringTriangle = "x"
        for x in range(height):
            print stringTriangle
            for x in range(1):
                stringTriangle+="xx"
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? Where would you like to append spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with `range(1)` but you can do `string * iterations (int)` to achieve multiple characters.

Comment: Look up string formatting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment

Comment: For example Triangle(11): http://pastebin.com/h4WRwffx

Comment: You can use a field width to format. Try:  `'{:^30}'.format('*')`

Comment: Try `print '\n'.join(['{:^20}'.format('x'*i) for i in range(1,20,2)])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a string containing `n` spaces, use `" "*n`. To concatenate two strings `a` and `b`, use `a + b`. To learn about other things that can be done with strings, see [Python 2: Built-in Types: `str` and Other Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

From there, you should be able to solve your homework problem by calculating how many spaces and how many asterisks you need in each line of the figure.

Comment: Is it possible to remove a certain number of spaces? For example https://repl.it/Do3C/0 in this case, how would I be able to remove 1 space from newstr?

Comment: To remove the first character, use a subsequence `s[1:]`. Read the Sequence Types link.