# How can I add a new row which shows the number of columns into my code

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have lists as shown below:

```
l1=['N  N  N  N  M  M  M  W  W  N  W  W','N  W  W  W  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N']
l2=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

And here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    print(l2[i],l1[i])
```

My output is:

```
A N  N  N  N  M  M  M  W  W  N  W  W
B N  W  W  W  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N
```

I want a output like that (without using 3rd party libraries):

```
A N  N  N  N  M  M  M  W  W  N  W  W
B N  W  W  W  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

I've tried something like that but it didn't work:

```
l3=[j for j in l1[0] if j!=' ']
print("  ",end='')
for k in range(len(l3)):
    print("{}  ".format(k),end='')
```

and output is like that:

```
A N  N  N  N  M  M  M  W  W  N  W  W
B N  W  W  W  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

Comment: For what I see, your only problem are the trailing spaces before the numbers when they have 2 digits, is it right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450472/how-to-format-print-output-or-string-into-fixed-width - Take a look into that when it comes to formatting.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: If this is the case, just decide the number of `spaces` your `print` will add, based on the number of characters your index `j` has, so adding 1 less space if your number has digits:
`print(" " * (3 - len(j) ))` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python 3.6+, you can use formatted string literals ([PEP489](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
l1 = ['N  N  N  N  M  M  M  W  W  N  W  W', 'N  W  W  W  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N']
l2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

for i, j in zip(l2, l1,):
    print(f'{i:>3}', end='')
    j_split = j.split()
    for val in j_split:
        print(f'{val:>3}', end='')
    print('\n', end='')

print(f'{"":>3}', end='')
for idx in range(len(j_split)):
    print(f'{idx:>3}', end='')
```

Result:

```
  A  N  N  N  N  M  M  M  W  W  N  W  W
  B  N  W  W  W  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want characters and digits are right aligned.
Modify last string formatting

```
print('{}'.format(..))
```

into

```
print(' { :>n}'.format(..))
```

Where `n` in this case is 2.

Answer is based on the 
[Python: Format output string, right alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using string formatting:

```
l3=[j for j in l1[0] if j!=' ']
for k in range(len(l3)):
    print('%3s'%" {}".format(k),end='')
```

Output is:

```
A N  N  N  N  M  M  M  W  W  N  W  W
B N  W  W  W  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```