# python: Read a table from file (created from prettytable) and mantain spaces

Tags: python, pygtk, prettytable

Let's say I have the following file.txt

```
$ cat file.txt
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adelaide  | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
| Brisbane  | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
| Darwin    | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
| Hobart    | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
| Sydney    | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
| Perth     | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

If I try reading the file like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
```

And then I try to display each line using the gtk2.0 textbuffer (similar to print):

```
for eachline in lines:
    if idx == 0:
        self.textbuffer.delete(start, end)
        end = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
        self.textbuffer.set_text(eachline)
    else:
        self.textbuffer.insert(end, eachline)
        end = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
```

I get the following output:

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adelaide |  1295 |  1158259 |      600.5      |
| Brisbane  | 5905  |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
| Darwin   | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
| Hobart   | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
| Sydney    | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
| Melbourne  | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
| Perth   | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

Any suggesstion how to make it look prettier (like the first table) ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you might want to format your strings like the following:

[Python: Format output string, right alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment) 
the with in the output like

```
for align, text in zip('<^>', ['left', 'center', 'right']): 
    '{0:{fill}{align}16}'.format(text, fill=align, align=align)
```

in the output, you can specify the with (or get that based on the length of your inputs).

I have not worked with gtk2.0 myself but perhaps it will help https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings