# Aligning text to be more symmetrical after a string

Tags: python, format, f-string

Hello I want to make text align so that it looks nicer. I want to print keys and corrsponding values from a dictionary.

```
for word in sorted(dict.keys()):
    print(f'{word}: {dict[word]}')
```

however this prints it like this

```
a:      4
c:  2
k:   444
```

I want it like this:

```
a:    4
c:    2
k:    444
```

Comment: Maybe this help: [Klick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
for key, value in sorted(dict.keys()):
    print(f'{key}: {value:>5}')
```

Reference [Python: Format output string, right alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment)