# Removing trailing whitespace for a tic tac toe board in python

Tags: python, removing-whitespace, trailing-whitespace

I am trying to resolve the error as highlighted in the picture below. I am able to print a tic-tac-toe board but the trailing whitespace affects the test case. I am not better yet at using strings to represent a list of numbers. The desired output is embedded in the image below:
[image: test case error]

```
def printBoard(plane):#function to print out the current board
    for w in range(len(plane)):
        for e in range(len(plane)):
            if plane[w][e]== 1:
                print('{:^3}'.format('X'), end="")
            elif plane[w][e] == -1:
                print('{:^3}'.format('O'), end="")
            elif plane[w][e] == 0:
                print('{:^3d}'.format((len(plane)*w+e)), end="")
        print()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example usage of this function?

Comment: @MichaelM.  This function initializes the tictactoe board from 0 - 36 before the players start appending "X" or "O"

Comment: It seems like this function you provided prints a board, not initializes one.

Comment: @MichaelM. yes..it prints the initial empty (with pure numbers only) board before we start "X" and "O" in the next player turns...sorry for the wording

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format output string, right alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/format-output-string-right-alignment)

Comment: side note: try to make future questions as *concise* and *short* as possible. Remove `'X'` and `'O'` related statements if they are not used. paste console / terminal output rather than inserting images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do want you want. Changed `end` to vary if it was the end of a line and used periods(.) to make the spaces visible for demonstration.  Refactored a bit to remove redundant code:

```py
def printBoard(plane):
    i=0
    for values in plane:
        for col,value in enumerate(values):
            text = ' X' if value==1 else ' O' if value==-1 else f'{i:2d}'
            print(text, end='\n' if col==len(values)-1 else '.')
            i += 1

plane = [[0]*6 for _ in range(6)]
printBoard(plane)
plane[1][1] = 1
plane[1][5] = 1
plane[2][2] = -1
plane[2][5] = -1
print()
printBoard(plane)
```

Output:

```
 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5
 6. 7. 8. 9.10.11
12.13.14.15.16.17
18.19.20.21.22.23
24.25.26.27.28.29
30.31.32.33.34.35

 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5
 6. X. 8. 9.10. X
12.13. O.15.16. O
18.19.20.21.22.23
24.25.26.27.28.29
30.31.32.33.34.35
```

Comment: Your illustration works well with the rest of my code...Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to right justify the numbers while also enforcing 3 characters of width so your printed board retains its formatting. To do this, you can eliminate the caret character from your print statements, which will allow the printed values to right justify. The caret signifies that you are centering the text, which will cause it to leave trailing character(s). This should eliminate your trailing whitespace:

```
print('{:3d}'.format((len(plane)*w+e)), end="")
```